# How to tune for slow mdbs?

Tags: wildfly, hornetq

I have created a simple MDB that sleeps for 1 sec (to simulate the network call it makes in real life). When I produce 100 messages there is a queue build up and it takes about 4 seconds to consume all of the messages. What should I tune to make it run all 100 messages simultaneously? I have tried:

```
 @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "100")
```

on the MDB and

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:2.0">
        <hornetq-server>
         <thread-pool-max-size>500</thread-pool-max-size>
```

in the Wildfly config

Comment: It seems the mdb-strict-max-pool might be involved increasing this brought down the time considerably. But please don't hesitate to give an answer if you have one :)

Comment: as you have already found out, jboss comes from a default pool of 20 MDB, what would make your test last for around 5 seconds. Increasing it to 100 should bring it down to 1 second